# In-page Google Analytics giving no page views recorded

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to use Google In-Page Analytics.  The rest of Google Analytics seems to work correctly on my site, but when I go to the new In-page analytics, I get no click appearing.  I just get an error saying "There are no pageviews recorded for this page. Try adjusting the date range or select an alternate page."  To the left in the content details it tells the number of page views.

Do I need to setup something special for In-Page anayltics to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the reason this was failing was that I was using a filter.  I removed the filter from my GA account and after a while it started working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you waited at least 24 hours?

Google Analytics can take up to a day (sometimes a *little* longer) to parse all of your information.

Comment: I have had Google Analytics setup on the site for almost a year

Comment: @Nicolo77 - I'm talking about the length of time it can take new traffic data to be posted

Comment: @Nicolo77 - "What about now?"